# How do I import a CSV in Bokeh as a ColumnDataSource without going through Pandas?

Tags: bokeh

To use a dataset in Bokeh, it is common to import pandas as well and use a Pandas DataFrame as data. It is also possible to create ColumnDataSource from Pandas DataFrame.

But is it possible to go straight from a csv file (or any other tabular source data) to Bokeh without creating using Pandas as a bridge, and how?

Answer (score 1):

Bokeh `ColumnDataSource` are built directly from python dictionaries. Simply use:

```
ColumnDataSouce(data=dict(...))
```

Without knowing your specific data format, I'd refer to you to use many of the other answers on SO on reading a csv file and creating a Python dictionary. You can also take a look at the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) on `DictReader`.